# Yii Framework database relations in models

Tags: php, relational-database, yii

I am doing a small POS application in [Yii Framework](http://www.yiiframework.com/). I have my database looking like this.
Now I have done the part for model and crud. But here I am little bit confused with the building relation among them. So can some one kindly tell me what will be the relations among them in models? Any help and suggestions will be really appreciable. Thanks..

```
====================
      mspl_sales
====================
id
product_id
store_id
discount_id
agent_id
date
price
discount_percentage


===================
mspl_requistitation
===================
id
store_id
product_id
agent_id
date
requisition_number
procure_quantity
balance_store_stock
priority



==================
   mspl_product
==================
id
product_name
cost_price
selling_price



==================
  mspl_store
=================
id
store_name
store_location



==================
    mspl_discount
==================
id
discount_type


=================
mspl_agent
===============
id
user_name
email_id
agent_code
authorization_password
```

Comment: If you setup foreign keys in mysql then run Gii it creates them automatically for you FYI. Are you asking how to create a relationship or what your relationships are?

Answer (score 0):

There are different types of relations in Yii.
Most common are:

- One to many
- One to one
- Many to many

As far as I can see you only have one to many and maybe a view one to one relations.
A model in Yii is an object, which is stored as a record in your database.

In your database you have the table sales.
This table has a store id, so a sale has one store, a store has many sales, so this is a one to many relation.

In the Yii framework this is represented as follows: your sale model has an attribute store_id, but it also has a relation to a store model and there-for it has this store model. so you can access the store model form your sale model as follows:

`$sale->store`

From there you can access all the attributes a store has, like its name and location.

`$sale->store->location`

or

```
$store = $sale->store;
$store->location
```

A store on the other hand has an array of sales models. so if your store model has 1 sale, it would be accesable like this:

`$store->sales[0]`

If your store has more sales you can iterate through them:

```
foreach($store->sales as $sale){
    $sale->id = 0;
    $sale->save();
    //your logic here
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: In the store table, you can add another field (you might need product id as a foreign key).

Step 2: Then in the store table goto structure select foreign key click index, at last click relation view (under structure it provided), there select foreign key table name and id, type as "cascade".

Step 3: Then again regenerate model and you will get the relation.